# Sending email in zimbra using JS-Zimbra error

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, zimbra

I'm trying to do a search quest using js-zimbra module, i keep on getting an error that i didn't knew how to fix,

her's my code :

```
var z = require('js-zimbra');

var comm = new z.Communication({
  url: "myzimbraurl/service/soap"
});

// Authenticate

comm.auth({
   "username": "user",
    "secret": "pass",
    "isPassword": true
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
    // An error occured authenticating!        
}
console.log('done !')
    // Now, carry on creating requests and sending them
comm.getRequest({}, function(err, req) {
    if (err) {
        // Can't create a new request
    }
    req.addRequest({
        name: "SearchRequest",
        namespace: "zimbraMail",
        params: {
            "SearchRequest" : {
                "types" : "message",
                "fetch" : "all"     
            },
            "query": {
                "_content": "in:inbox"
            }
        }
    }, function(err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        }
        comm.send(req, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err', err);
            }
            console.log(res);
        })
      })
    })
 });
```

and when i execute i got the following error message :

> error: Received server error: {"Code":{"Value":"soap:Receiver"},"Reason":{"Text":"error while proxying request to target server: Connection reset"},"Detail":{"Error":{"Code":"service.PROXY_ERROR","Trace":"","_jsns":"urn:zimbra"}}}

Is there any fix for such error ?

Comment: What is the real value of `url: "resource-link"` ? It should be your Zimbra connection URL. BTW your snippet does a `SearchRequest` not a `SendMessageRequest`

Comment: @NabIlovich, yeah i modified the question my bad, the resource link here i mean with it my Zimbra Soap End point :  zimbraurl/service/soap

Comment: Does you zimbra server listen on port 80 or 443 ? Or both maybe ?

Comment: Well the site is on https and http both so both 80 and 443.

Comment: According to the documentation some required params are missing : https://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.6.0/api-reference/index.html

Comment: I tested all given parameter in boomerang and everything worked like charm, with those parameters.